# Why SonarQube complains about generic Exception when the exception has been changed to custom one

Tags: java, generics, exception, sonarqube

I've been tasked to make JUnit tests for an application that someone else made along time, I can't modify the original code, so when I encounter something like this:

```java
public String clean(String url) throws Exception {
    if (url.indexOf(invalidURL) {
        throw new Exception("Severe XSSS detected");
    }
}
```

I write my test with: throws Exception, and SonarQube complains about generic Exception and if I write a custom exception like: `public class MyException extends Exception`, still SonarQube doesn't like it, any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: "still sonarqube doesn't like it" ?

Comment: You could be more precise: What is the exact error message from SonarQube? This could help understanding which rule kicks in here. SonarQube is using a lot of tools with hundreds of rules…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The existing answers provide useful information, but if the constraints you specify in your original post are correct, those answers don't really help.

If you can't actually modify the code under test, there is no way you can fix the SonarQube issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm interpreting your code: Looks like you have an invalid URL somewhere and you don't want to do your business stuff, if the parameter `url` contains this invalid URL. So I would guess that an `IllegalArgumentException` is much more precise than the generic `Exception`.

From the JavaDoc of `IllegalArgumentException`:

> Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or inappropriate argument.

Furthermore, I would assume that SonarQube will accept an `IllegalArgumentException` at this point without grumbling.

Answer (score 0):

`MyException` extends `Exception`, so you have to change the method declaration too - the `throws` statement:

```java
public String clean(String url) throws MyException {
   if (url.indexOf(invalidURL) {
      throw new MyException("Severe XSSS detected");
   }
}
```

The change is safe because the code is compatible with the previous option:

```
try {
    object.clean("invalidUrl")
} catch (Exception e) {
    // MyException is handled by this catch block
}
```

Comment: I am not allowed to change the method declaration, but thanks for the help, I ended using "//NOSONAR" to avoid this code smell

Comment: Why you are not allowed? It works at the same way, but without any code smell issues. `// NOSONAR` is a very bad solution. It hides the problem, not fix it. It also hides all other problems in the specified line, so you won't be informed about all new potentially introduced issues in the future.

Comment: I've been tasked only to make junit tests, not to fix the original code of the system covered, i'ts an old system and many other systems depend of it, to make one small change requires permission from many departments